# How to assign a css attributes to a table in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I created a new table as a content element and I want to include my css file, but I can't find an option. Recently I found a youtube video with an "Additional css" option, but I don't have this one, unfortunately.

I have already included my css file to `fileadmin/` under `Filelist`. I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: no need to apologize for you English it's fine

Answer (score 0):

Here are the related Docs: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Setup/Page/Index.html#includecss-array

Search for `page = PAGE` in your project and add the `includeCSS` lines:

```
page = PAGE
page {

  # ... many things
  # ... Add the following

  includeCSS {
    file1 = fileadmin/yourCssFile.css
  }

}
```

This should fix your problem, but putting the CSS into your `fileadmin/` is not best practice.

I recommend you to read the Site Package Tutorial: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-sitepackage/master/en-us/

You can have a look at the Site Package Builder and see how it is done there: https://sitepackagebuilder.com/

You can ask further questions here in stack overflow or sign up in Slack: https://typo3.slack.com/

Wish you fun!

Comment: Sorry, I am a complete layman. I haven't done anything in typo3. Where should I search for page = PAGE? In the menu in typo3 or in the file explorer? I heard that page is not automatically initialized.

Comment: Thats ok, but I have no idea what you got so far, `page = PAGE` should be somewhere in a file with a `.txt`, `.ts` or `.typoscript` ending. If your using an IDE, there should be a way to search inside all files. In PhpStorm, click on the top folder and press `ctrl + shift + f` and search `page = PAGE`. But it is also possible that is not there or in the Database. So again, I would strongly recommend reading https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-sitepackage/master/en-us/